# constructing a joined django query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm interacting with a legacy db on another system, so the models are written in stone and not very django-ey.

My `models.py`:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    site_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=300)

class Document(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    site_ref = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)

class DocumentStatusCategory(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=90)

class DocumentStatus(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    status = models.ForeignKey(DocumentStatusCategory)
    changed_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

In my `views.py` I want to retrieve a queryset with all the `Document` objects that belong to a specified `Site` (say `site_ref=mysite`) which do **not** have any related `DocumentStatus` objects with `status=4`.

Any idea how I can do this as a single (non-sql intensive) line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Document.objects.filter(site_ref=mysite).exclude(documentstatus__status_id=4)
```

Comment: Keep forgetting the relation span across a reverse relation. Can't it just be `documentstatus__status_id` though?

Comment: aha, I didn't know you could call the relation like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Document.objects.filter(site_ref=site_obj).exclude(documentstatus_set__in=DocumentStatus.objects.filter(status_id=4))
```

Not exactly one query, but I don't think that's achievable without going down to raw sql. Two queries isn't bad though I suppose.

I should mention that the above assumes that the reverse relation between Document and DocumentStatus is `documentstatus_set`. You can explicitly state what the reverse relation is like so:

```
# inside the DocumentStatus model definition
document = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='document_statuses')
```

Then the query becomes:

```
Document.objects.filter(site_ref=site_obj).exclude(document_statuses__in=DocumentStatus.objects.filter(status_id=4))
```